Update iOS App Badge Count automatically for recipient's device when an FCM push notification is triggered?
We're building our app with FlutterFlow and a Firebase backend. To send push notifications, we're using FCM and we're trying to update the recipient's iOS App Badge Count when they receive a push notification. This currently works on Android, but not iOS. I've spoken with the FlutterFlow product team and apparently they are blocked from solving this issue because of this Firebase issue (https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/issues/9563).
I have to believe that not all Flutter apps that use Firebase are blocked from updating their badge count on ioS? Any workarounds to this issue would be greatly appreciated.
Right now when I trigger a push notification in FlutterFlow, the recipient receives the notification, but the exterior app badge does not show up.
Within FlutterFlow, you are able to write custom cloud functions, so I figure it's possible to write a custom cloud function to update the recipient user's payload when the sender triggers the push. However, hoping for advice on how to best proceed.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
